# How can I refactor this method to return the most recent date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to find the most recent time a contact was marked "done". Contacts belong to a User. I have this method in my User Model, but I know it can probably be improved.

```
  def last_contact_done_days
      date_array = self.contacts.find(:all, :select => "date_done").to_a
      most_recent = date_array.max
      last_done_days_ago = Date.today - most_recent[:date_done]
      return last_done_days_ago
  end
```

Thanks!

Comment: The question needs clarification -- if you want to return a DateTime (which your text says), that's one thing, if you want to return the duration, then that's a little different.  I suggest returning DateTime (or nil), in which case the answers by @MrYoshiji work -- you could pass the date to the `time_ago_in_words` DateHelper method.  But in either case, you'll probably need to check for nil.

Comment: @tharrison, good point. The goal was to find the number of days ago, but you're right that if I just return the date then i can use time_ago_in_words to calculate the number of days. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this method:

```
def last_contact_done_days # => date_done of the most recent contact if it exists
  contact = self.contacts.order('date_done DESC').first
  return contact.date_done if contact
  nil
end
```

OR (**shorter version** with [try](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/Object%3atry) method):

```
def last_contact_done_days
  self.contacts.order('date_done DESC').first.try(:date_done)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine it this way :

```
def last_contact_done_days
  Date.today - contacts.order('date_done DESC').first.date_done
end
```